# How to handle many players in a multiplayer level?

Tags: networking, network-programming

i would like to program a game where many players are in the same level. Lets say it's just 2D and there is a maximum of 65,535 players. With following data that is sent to the client for info about one player in the level:

```
8 Bytes - Player ID
8 Bytes - Player X Position
8 Bytes - Player Y Position
8 Bytes - Player Rotation
```

32 bytes for 65,535 players would mean 2,097,120 bytes (about 2 MB) for one update of every player in the level. If this happens at 30fps it would require 60MB/sec. So how can i handle that much players in one level with lower bandwidth usage?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to update *all* 2^16 players at once? Or does it suffice to update a relevant subset?

Comment: i'm just thinking of the case that maximum players are in one level and everyone is moving, which shouldn't lead to lags/crashes

Comment: Why don't you optimize for the common case, or is this indeed a scenario you anticipate with reasonable probability?

Comment: i hope this game will get popular enough to get that much players ;)

Comment: I recommend reading the quake sourcecode. Here is a review of the networking section: http://fabiensanglard.net/quakeSource/quakeSourceNetWork.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1) Generally speaking, not every player will see every other player at the same time.  You can optimize this by only sending data to players within a certain distance (probably a little wider than what they can see to smooth out movement around the edges of vision.

2) Just because your game is running at 30fps doesn't mean it needs to receive 30 updates/sec from the server.  You can send less frequent updates and interpolate the frames in between.  Latency is going to be variable, so you'll need to do some of that already.

3) You only need to send information that's changed, so if there were up updates, assume no change.  Maybe occasionally (every 5 seconds or something) send the full set of visible data whether a change happened or not to account for lost packets, but only do that if you start seeing issues.

Answer (score 1):

- For  65,535 players, you need 2 bytes of id-variable.
- If minimum rotation angle is 0.005 degrees, you need 2 bytes for
  0-360 degree range.

So, it is 20 bytes(%37 reduction of data now).

If a player is not moving or rotating, then there is no need to send X,Y or rotation data right? You can add 1-byte informer as a " no need to update X" or "no need to rotate" or "player offline"

You can even use 32 bit integers for X,Y variables and update only when the floating-point variants round to next integer value(this isnt a physics game isnt it?).

Design your game in a way that every player has a cache of other players positions, when they dont move, just use cache.

You can use [spatial indexing/octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) to group nearby-players to achieve faster-updates for near players(others dont update when unnecesary(what is your players sight range?)).

Comment: thanks! but isn't it possible with UDP that some packages aren't received? so sending only changes could result in wrong display.

Comment: So you want a full-structure data? Ofcourse data can be lost anytime. Probability is important i think

Comment: There is ogame that naerly 50000 players online at some time and update rate is so slow

Answer (score 1):

Typically, most players can't see other players.

Only send updates to players for the players they can see (or will are close to being able to see).